# GoogleTest: main() in different lib -> test cases not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, googletest

I have various executable projects in my VS solution that contain various GoogleTest cases. I tried to reduce the code by having a separate .lib project that contains nothing more than the `main()` function and GoogleTest's initialization code. I could then link this into all the exe projects that contain the actual tests:

So:

```
---main.cpp in static lib project TESTMAIN---

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

And

```
---accounttest.cpp in exe project TESTACCOUNT

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct BankAccount
{
    int m_iBalance;

    BankAccount(){}
};

TEST(AccountTests, BankAccountStartsEmpty)
{
    BankAccount account;
    EXPECT_EQ(0, account.m_iBalance);
}
```

However, when running TESTACCOUNT.exe, the unit tests are not picked up:

```
Running main() from gmock_main.cc
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

When explicitly adding a `main()` (with gtest init code) to my exe project, it does work. My hunch is that it has to do with the linker, but I am not exactly sure why this isn't working. I still would like to avoid adding a main+init to all my test projects..

Any suggestions on good ways to doing this would be really appreciated.

Ben

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you tried linking against gtest-main instead of your lib?

Comment: gtest provides a `gtest_main` which is exactly what you're doing (use that instead). When you use the `TEST` macro it registers your test via [this function](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/b4d4438df9479675a632b2f11125e57133822ece/googletest/src/gtest.cc#L2575) in static initialization time. I can't tell from just what you've written, but it looks to me like you're getting 2 test registrars - it's not that hard to generally get multiple versions of globals like this with dynamic libraries, but I don't know how it's possible with your setup.

Comment: ah, that might be a good idea. I'll give it a try, thank you both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David and @Michal Walenciak noted, it worked by linking to gtest_main. In the end, I think I didn't need to link to a static lib, but to a DLL.